# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 connects to SQL 2012 localdb

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, localdb

is it possible to use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to connect to instances of SQL 2012 localdb?
I have installed the 2012 Native Client, which contains the ODBC driver, but I still can't seem to use the SSMS 2008 to connect to my localdb instance.
I have no problem using the sqlcmd to connect to the localdb, so it is not the server problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install CU6 on system with SSMS 2008R2 as it contains some fixes related to compatibility issues with SQL Server 2012.

If you can see the 2012 server in your SSMS 2008R2 than you have connected it.

Open a new query window and execute the following code:

```
 select @@version
```

Comment: I'm actually surprised this worked... SSMS 2008 R2 is a .NET 3.5 application and .NEt 3.5 doesn't understand LocalDB connection strings.

Comment: It turns out that I have to use the name pipe to connect to the localdb, I can't use (localdb)\dbname. But other than that, it worked

Answer (score 2):

You could do it via named pipes this way:

1 - Get the address of a (localdb) instance by running the following command: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" info [InstanceName] (if its the default instance you're interested in, specify v11.0 as the [InstanceName] You can write it in CMD to text file with the command:

**"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" info v11.0 > C:\db_details.txt**

2 - Copy the "Instance pipe name" value, e.g. **np:.\pipe\LOCALDB#1E0FF40B\tsql\query**

3 - Paste the "Instance pipe name" value as the Server Name.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

ip Address\sqlserver2012 in the server name.

then set the Authentication method  = SQL Server Authentication and provide thw login and password fields.